# Why the Node Labels Aren't Fully Visible in the 3D Coordinate System using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to include axis labels x, y, and z at the head of each axis in my code. However, I'm experiencing an issue where the x and y labels are not fully displayed. Below, you'll find my code and the output, with the issue highlighted in red. Can you help me understand why the x and y labels are not fully visible?

**CODE:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \begin{axis}[
                        axis lines = center,
                        ticks=none,
                        xmin=-2, xmax=2,
                        ymin=-2, ymax=2,
                        zmin=0, zmax=2,
                        view={135}{25},
                    ]

                    %% adding axis labels
                    \node at (axis cs:2.1,0,0) {$x$};
                    \node at (axis cs:0,2.1,0) {$y$};
                    \node at (axis cs:0,0,2.1) {$z$};
            
        \end{axis}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: Your labels are clipped because by default `pgfplots` clips everything that goes outside the plot area. You can avoid this using `clip mode= individual` to avoid that for explicit node or draw commands. But the solution by @JohnSmith of using proper labels it's better.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
Using the `anchor` property
[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \begin{axis}[
                        axis lines = center,
                        ticks=none,
                        xmin=-2, xmax=2,
                        ymin=-2, ymax=2,
                        zmin=0, zmax=2,
                        view={135}{25},
                        xlabel={$x$},
                        ylabel={$y$},
                        zlabel={$z$},
                        xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, anchor=east},
                        ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, anchor=west},
                        zlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, anchor=south}
                    ]
        \end{axis}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Or this:

[image]
Adjust Label Positions:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \begin{axis}[
                        axis lines = center,
                        ticks=none,
                        xmin=-2, xmax=2.2, % Adjusted xmax
                        ymin=-2, ymax=2.2, % Adjusted ymax
                        zmin=0, zmax=2,
                        view={135}{25}, % You might want to adjust this
                    ]

                    % Adjusted label positions
                    \node at (axis cs:2.0,-0.25,0) {$x$}; % Moved x label a bit further
                    \node at (axis cs:0.25,2.0,0) {$y$}; % Moved y label a bit further
                    \node at (axis cs:0,0,2.1) {$z$};
            
        \end{axis}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Or you could use pgfplots built in label:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \begin{axis}[
                        axis lines = center,
                        ticks=none,
                        xmin=-2, xmax=2,
                        ymin=-2, ymax=2,
                        zmin=0, zmax=2,
                        view={135}{25},
                        xlabel={$x$},
                        ylabel={$y$},
                        zlabel={$z$},
                    ]
        \end{axis}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]